# "Service Unavailable" Error

Tags: installation

I'm having a problem installing locally on my Mac (using MAMP Pro, Sequel Pro).  I followed all the steps in the Mijingo installation video - plus a few others.  When I go to install Craft CMS I get the following error message:

> Service Unavailable  Our site is temporarily unavailable.  Please try again later."

I checked terminal and `.htaccess` appears hidden under the public directory.  I changed the permissions.  And the config file appears to be pointing in the correct places.

What might I be missing? ...or at the very least, how do I delete and start again fresh?  Is it as simple as deleting the Craft files and starting over again or are there hidden files that need to be addressed before I can start clean again?

Comment: There is no other error message.  Just a box with the text referenced.

Comment: Have you visited the /admin path?  Sometimes I get this error when I need to finish updating or creating the db.

Comment: @RockwellRice  ...well now I feel stupid.  I was launching from MAMP instead of typing the URL in my browser.  So, yeah that worked.  Thanks

Comment: @Hellyar Can you add what worked for you as an official answer? Will help in case someone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing permission on a folder in the `/craft` directory. Best thing to do, is just retrace your steps by following the official [install guide](https://craftcms.com/docs/installing).

I don't use MAMP though, so there might be extra stuff you need to do, but if you scroll down to the bottom of that page to the [Additional Resources](https://craftcms.com/docs/installing#additional-resources) section. There are some other links to articles which might help, in particular this one:

[Installing Craft CMS on Mac OS X Using MAMP & Sequel Pro](http://a73cram5ay.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/installing-craft-cms-on-mac-os-x-using.html)

If you do want to start again then you should be safe to delete the `/craft` folder and try again. Although unless you're missing files, you shouldn't really need to start again.

Comment: First, thanks... That is exactly what I did.  I first tried using the Mijingo approach, which to me seems identica as a73cram5ayl.  Then I ran it exactly as outlined by a73cram5ay under Additional Resources.  Either way, I still get the same "Service Unavailable" error message, with no other error reference, etc.

Comment: Is there a way (in terminal) to check the permission for each file to see if the chmod -R 744 craft/app took?   I tried using the command ls -l app, ls -l config and ls -l storage.  But, 744 does not appear in any of the lists.

Comment: see above, I just tried a 4th time with a clean install.  I'm still getting the same error.  Thoughts?  This is kind of sad.

Comment: @hellyar ls -lah will give you a list and permissions of folders / files, but to me it seems that you might not be able to connect to the database.

Please try your url and point to /admin it might give you a more useful error message